# Append data into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i am reading file.txt, which has following data :

```
     Arjun   10th  20     88+

      +       77   76      36
```

How to make class as a key and add other values to corresponding key.which will look like
{'10th' :['20',[88,77,76,36]]}

Note : values in line ends with + sign and next line starts with + sign, How can we insert them into same list?

Comment: Please correct your formatting. As it stands, I am not sure what indentation and blank lines your file actually contains.

Comment: Is this a practical or a theoretical questions? It is unclear what you are asking. If its a practical question, what language are you using?

Comment: @user3347570: Please add the appropriate tags to your question to indicate the language you're using. Also, have a look at the markdown syntax description/editing help to properly format your question and your comments in a readable way.

Comment: display your text file format.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper; this is how the format looks like. And I am using python script to read the file data, help me to insert the data to dictionary  : student_data as mentioned in question

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far, and what precisely is wrong with it. Can you read the file? Access each line?

Comment: I wrote code to read file and append data to dictionary but, I dont know, how can we append the lines starting with + to same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite that the question is not well explained, I suppose that what you try to do is something like this. Check the function `words` please and tell me whether this is more or less in the proper direction.

```
def words(d, auxList):
    # Variables to save state between lines
    curKey = None
    values = []

    for line in auxList:
        items = line.split()
        # Check if we have values already from a previous line
        if curKey is None:
            # Check if we see a continuation symbol (+)
            if items[-1][-1] == '+':
                # and remove it from the value
                items[-1] = items[-1][:-1]
                # Save the info in this line
                curKey = items[1]
                values = items[2:]
            else:
                # If all the information is in one simple line
                d[items[1]] = items[2:]
        else:
            # Check if we see a continuation symbol (+)
            if items[-1][-1] == '+':
                # and remove it from the value
                items[-1] = items[-1][:-2]
                # Save the info in this line and accumulate it
                # with the previous ones
                values.extend(items[1:])
            else:
                # Update dictionary when we have all the values
                d[curKey] = values + items[1:]
                # and reset state
                curKey = None
                values = []

    # Be sure to save the last line if there is no more info
    # Maybe it is not necessary
    if curKey is not None:
        d[curKey] = values


d = {}
a2 = [line.strip() for line in myfile.readlines()]
words(d, a2)
```

Comment: :It is working for the purpose! Can u suggest me, how to separate values in the dictionary <d> with commas (,) ?

Can u also suggest me, how do I separate values by eight spaces using comma??

Comment: If you want the value to be a string with all the numbers separated by commas, you should replace, for instance, the instruction `d[items[1]] = items[2:]` for `d[items[1]] = ', '.join(items[2:])`. In any case, you need to give more details when you ask a question here. Provide an example of how the input (and the output) should look like and some (pseudo?-)code would also be useful.